# Animate existing drop down menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML

```
<header>
  <a class="show-menu">Menu</a>
  <nav>
    <a>anchor1</a>
    <a>anchor2</a>
    <a>anchor3</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The CSS currently hides the nav anchors until the button is clicked, then the jquery toggles the class attribute to change display:none to display:block.

This is the current JS which successfully displays the list when Menu is clicked, but I'm trying to animate it, so that when the button is clicked the list will slide into position.

```
$(function() {
  $('a.show-menu').click(function() {
  $('header nav').toggleClass('active');
  });
  });
```

Comment: Did you try `slideToggle` instead of toggling the class using `toggleClass`?

Comment: Yes, the toggleClass is necessary to enable the display:block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('a.show-menu').click(function() {
  $('header nav').slideToggle(function(){$(this).toggleClass('active')});
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^and toggle your class if you want
  //or can you use simple slideToggle(); 
  });
  });
```

reference **[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)**

Comment: This one is the closest, however the list names load unevenly. The first one loads instantly and then the rest of them load once the slide is complete. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How about jQuery Slide Toggle?

```
$(function() {
  $('a.show-menu').click(function() {
  $('header nav').slideToggle();
  });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5FZmd/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI extends the jQuery native **toggleClass** to take second optional parameter: **duration**

```
toggleClass( class, [duration] )
```

[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/).